# WordPress orderby multiple meta_key not working

Tags: wordpress

first post here, usually I found answer without posting but this time I'm stuck, I hope you can help.

I create my own custom theme for wordpress, and in a loop I try to order my result sorting multiple meta_key,
first on date, then on nationality, then on machine type

for exemple I would have

```
13/03/2021 Italian Motocross
12/03/2021 Italian Supermoto
12/03/2021 French Motocross
13/03/2021 French Supermoto
12/03/2021 Italian Motocross
12/03/2021 German Motocross
13/03/2021 Italian Supermoto
12/03/2021 Italian Motocross
13/03/2021 French Supermoto
12/03/2021 Italian Supermoto
```

and I want it to be

```
12/03/2021 French Motocross
12/03/2021 Italian Motocross
12/03/2021 Italian Motocross
12/03/2021 Italian Supermoto
12/03/2021 Italian Supermoto
12/03/2021 German Motocross
13/03/2021 French Supermoto
13/03/2021 French Supermoto
13/03/2021 Italian Motocross
13/03/2021 Italian Supermoto
```

here are the two method I tried none of those work

First one

```
  'post_type' => 'registration', 
  'posts_per_page' => -1, 
  'orderby' => array(
       'registration_date' => 'ASC',
       'register_country' => 'ASC',
       'register_machine' => 'ASC',
   ),
```

Second one

```
'post_type' => 'registration', 
  'posts_per_page' => -1, 
  'orderby' => 'registration_date register_country register_machine',
  'order' => 'ASC',
```

I used ACF to create my meta_keys and the names are correct as I can order them when I use only one but when I try to combine not working anymore.

I hope someone will be able to help me :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are sorting by meta key, you need to specify it explicitly in the arguments

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => 'registration_date',
'order' => 'ASC'
```

Comment: yes but if I do that it will sort only the date, I also need after to sort by nationality and then by machine